# How to use Neo4j bolt driver along with native Java API of an embedded neo4j db?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

We have one application built using Neo4j 3.0.4 embedded db. This application is responsible to build Graph.
We have another application built using Spring Data Neo4j 4.1. This application is responsible to get the Graph db data for UI.

As we do not have the capability of using traversal API in SDN4, Is there any possibility to use native Neo4j Java API in SDN4 application?
How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an embedded driver for neo4j-ogm which SDN is built on, the SDN and OGM docs have examples on how to use it.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference:configuration:driver:embedded

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the question is first application is started using GraphDatabaseService instance and had acquired lock on neo4j db. Would it be fine for SDN4 to start with embedded db again?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your Neo4j embedded application through the bolt interface (This might be 3.1+ only).

You can then start your SDN application in a separate JVM and connect to your embedded instance using the bolt driver.

Otherwise it is not possible to use an embedded instance controlled by another `main` and SDN embedded together.